# Reloading ResourceManager: Default

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I had a pi 3b sitting around for 2 years and I figured I would try to make it into a minecraft server. I have gotten everything until I run the command: tail -f /opt/minecraft/server/logs/latest.log It then gets stuck on Reloading ResourceManager: Default I reset my pi 3 times and tried each time and nothing has worked. If anyone needs anything extra to help please let me know! Thanks!

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git build-essential
sudo raspi-config

//Navigate to “Advanced Options” using key up or key down and press Enter.
//Select “GL Driver” and hit Enter.
//Select “GL (Fake KMS)”, press Enter.
//Select the “Finish” button, press Enter. When prompted “Would you like 
to reboot now?” select “Yes” and hit Enter.

sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
sudo useradd -r -m -U -d /opt/minecraft -s /bin/bash minecraft
sudo su - minecraft
mkdir -p ~/{tools,server}
cd ~/tools && git clone https://github.com/Tiiffi/mcrcon.git
cd ~/tools/mcrcon
gcc -std=gnu11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O2 -s -o mcrcon mcrcon.c
wget
```

https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/3dc3d84a581f14691199cf6831b71ed1296a9fdf/server.jar
-P ~/server
cd ~/server
java -Xms512M -Xmx768M -jar server.jar nogui
nano ~/server/eula.txt

```
//eula=true

nano ~/server/server.properties

rcon.port=25575
rcon.password=manchesterunited
enable-rcon=true


exit

sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/minecraft.service


[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=minecraft
Nice=1
KillMode=none
SuccessExitStatus=0 1
ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full
PrivateDevices=true
NoNewPrivileges=true
WorkingDirectory=/opt/minecraft/server
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx900M -Xms600M -jar server.jar nogui
ExecStop=/opt/minecraft/tools/mcrcon/mcrcon -H 108.17.159.44 -P 25575 -p 
manchesterunited stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start minecraft
sudo systemctl status minecraft
tail -f /opt/minecraft/server/logs/latest.log
```

Comment: Please post the EXACT steps you took and the commands you executed to make your Minecraft server

Comment: I finished adding what I have on my instruction page, it doesnt show output